# Playing a SCORM or xAPI content package

Tags: scorm2004, lrs

I want to create a xAPI compatible LMS which would share data from a LRS.
I wanted my UI to be completely separate from LMS ie I want LMS as REST services but I am unable to find a way to play/view SCORM or xAPI content files yet.

Can please someone elaborate how would this be possible?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm trying to do the same

Answer (score 1):

Hi xAPI is endpoint based.  Meaning the content has a targeted server in which it communicates with.  There is nothing for you to implement on a traditional LMS.

SCORM searches the DOM on the LMS for a JavaScript public object called API_1484_11 or API in SCORM 1.2. This requires you to expose this runtime API value for the content to communicate with.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, Is window.API_1484_11 required to play both the tin can content and SCORM content or playing xAPI content requires something else

Comment: xAPI uses a Learner Record Store.  So the content is going to talk to a endpoint provided by the Author/Creator.  That endpoint will be outside your control.  This standard was created to use more of a twitter style approach to training - to put it simply.  This is a distinction with the traditional AICC/SCORM model vs a ActivityStream approach which xAPI modeled after.